# Search by data range and another filter

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm looking for a way to search by date range and by another filter as in the following example.

```
protected void searchDB(Date dateInit, Date dateFinal, String name){
        db.collection("tagGroup")
                .whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("validity", dateInit)
                .whereLessThanOrEqualTo("validity", dateFinal)
                .whereEqualTo("name", name)
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                            List<String> tags = (List<String>) document.get("uiiList");
                            tagsList.addAll(tags);
                        }
                        if (tagsList.size() == 0){
                            showToast("Nothing found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            views.formCommon.fcEnabled();
                        }else {
                            inventoryList(tagsList);
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
```

It is written in the documentation that this does not work, can anyone have an idea to overcome and solve this problem?

Comment: Please add your database structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it adding a index of dateInitial with name and dateFinal with name.